# Hi, I have created the quantity button in my product page of shopify, but it is not passing the quantity value to the cart page

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I have created the quantity button in my product page of shopify, but it is not passing the quantity value to the cart page Here is my code:

```
<div class="qnty-control">
  <span class="minus">-</span>
  <input type="number" id="qntyInput" placeholder="1.0" step="0.25" min="0" max="10" name="quantity">
  <span class="plus">+</span>
</div>
```

Can some one please help

Answer (score 0):

Add `value="{{ item.quantity }}"` in the `#qntyInput` element.